# Mock and asset a function from an external library

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I'm struggling to figure out how to do this.

example.js

```
import Logger from "logging-library";

export default function example() {
  Logger.error(new Error("Example Error")):
}
```

example.test.js

```
test("will log an error", () => {
expect(Logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Error("Example Error");
});
```

The examples I've found might cover mocking an entire library, but don't seem to cover mocking and also asserting how it was called.

Comment: Did you try with const loggedError = jest.spyOn(Logger, "error");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unit test solution:

`example.js`:

```js
import Logger from 'logging-library';

export default function example() {
  Logger.error(new Error('Example Error'));
}
```

`example.test.js`:

```js
import Logger from 'logging-library';
import example from './example';

jest.mock(
  'logging-library',
  () => {
    return { error: jest.fn() };
  },
  { virtual: true },
);

describe('64858662', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  test('will log an error', () => {
    example();
    expect(Logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Error('Example Error'));
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64858662/example.test.js
  64858662
    ✓ will log an error (5ms)

------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 example.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.373s, estimated 12s
```